# Does this uncountable set of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ contain a dense set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I tried to find a different solution of the following problem:
If $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f$ attains every value exactly twice, $f$ cannot be continuous.

**My attempt:** $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, let $g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x,y)=f(x)-f(y)$. Let $f$ is continuous, then so is $g$. As $f$ attains every value exactly twice $f$ can't be constant, and as $f$ is continuous, $f$ is uncountable. Thus there are uncountably many pairs of points $(x,y)$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Thus $g$ sends uncountably many points of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $0$. Now if every uncountable set of $\mathbb{R}$ contains a dense set, then $g$ sends a dense set to $\{0\}$. Thus $g$ is $0$. But then $f$ is constant, contradiction. Thus $f$ isn't continuous.

**So the real problem**: Is it true that this uncountable set contains a set, dense in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, the interior of each disc is uncountable but not dense.

Comment: Dense in what? ${}{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown perhaps somewhere dense was intended. In particular, for every uncountable set $A$, does there exist some open neighborhood $U$ so that $A \cap U$ is dense in $U$

Comment: @AndresMejia Is that the case for the Cantor set inside $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Well, I didn't intend to say that the answer to the question was affirmative, just trying to make sense of it. This is likely the flavor of counterexample OP had in mind rather than the disk imo.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Why not use the intermediate value theorem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I would appeal to the major theorems about continuous functions on closed and bounded intervals.  For instance, there must be points $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$ and $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.  Let $M$ and $m$ be the maximum and minimum values of $f$ on $[a,b]$.  Either $M > 0$ or $m < 0$ (otherwise $f$ is constant, which would be a contradiction); assume without loss of generality that $M > 0$.

There exists $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = M$.  Then there exist $d$ and $e$ such that $ a < d < c < e < b$ and $f(d) = f(e) = M/2$.

There must be a second point $p$ with $f(p) = M$.  Cases:

1. If $p < a$, then there is a third point $q$ with $p < q < a$ and $f(q) = M/2$.
2. If $p > b$, then there is a third point $q$ with $b < q < p$ and $f(q) = M/2$.
3. If $a < p < b$ <s>then $f$ is constant on the interval between $c$ and $p$</s>, $f$ has a minimum $m'$ between $c$ and $p$.  Assume $p < c$; then we can find four points $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, and $r_4$ such that $a < r_1 < p < r_2 < r_3 < c < r_4$ and $f(r_i) = (M+m')/2$.

These all contradict the assumption that each value has exactly two points in its preimage.  OK, that's ugly; but perhaps you can simplify it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was about density of uncountable sets.

Comment: @Desire.  That's true.  I first read the question as "I am trying to solve this problem.  Here is my solution.  Here is where I am stuck."  I thought maybe an alternate solution would be welcome, that doesn't dead-end in this technicality.  Now I see the OP wrote that they sought a *different* solution; though it's not clear as to different from what.

Comment: If $p<a$ the interval $(0,M)$ is a subset of $f(\;(p,a)\;)$ and a subset of $f(\;(a ,c)\;)$ and a subset of $f(\;(c,b)\;)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is an uncountable subset of the plane that contains no dense subset (countable or not) of the plane. There are a lot more examples of course.

Comment: I know that, but R×{0} cannot be the inverse of {0} here, I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be a continuous function that achieves each value exactly twice.

Let $x < y$ so that $f(x) = f(y) = a$.  Let $w < v$ be so that $f(w) = f(v) = b > a$.  As a directly result of Intermediate value theorem either $x < w < v < y$ or $w < x < y < v$.

So let $A = \{x|$ if $f(x) = f(w)$ and $w \ne x$ then $x< w\}$ and $B = \{x|$ if $f(x) = f(w)$ and $w \ne x$ then $x> w\}$.

This basically a "cut".  All reals are either in $A$ or $B$.  Every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$.

So let $s= \sup A = \inf B$ and $(-\infty, s) \subset A$ and $(s, \infty) \subset B$.

So the question is, is $s \in A$ or is $s \in B$?  Either option leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I don't want a solution of that problem, I already know that. My question is different. I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If any uncountable subset of $\mathbb R^2$ contained a dense set, then—since supersets of dense sets are dense—this would mean that</s>

> any uncountable subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is dense.

This is clearly absurd.

---

In addition, it is easy to construct continuous, non-constant functions $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ is uncountable yet not dense, so your particular argument does not reveal any contradiction.

---

**ANSWER AMENDED**

Using the assumptions you made to obtain a contradiction, I will show that the set $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ cannot be dense in $\mathbb R^2$ (and hence nor can it contain any dense subset).

To see this, pick any $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. This is certainly possible because $f$ is obviously not constant. Without loss of generality, suppose that $f(x)<f(y)$ and let $$\alpha\equiv\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}.$$ Since $f$ is continuous, there exist $\varepsilon_x>0$ and $\varepsilon_y>0$ such that

- $f(z)<\alpha$ whenever $x-\varepsilon_x<z<x+\varepsilon_x$; and
- $f(z)>\alpha$ whenever $y-\varepsilon_y<z<y+\varepsilon_y$.

Let $\varepsilon\equiv\min\{\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_y\}$. Now, if $(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb R^2$ is within a circle of radius $\varepsilon$ centered around $(x,y)$, then $|z_1-x|<\varepsilon_x$ and $|z_2-y|<\varepsilon_y$, so that $$g(z_1,z_2)=f(z_1)-f(z_2)<\alpha-\alpha=0,$$ so that $(z_1,z_2)\notin g^{-1}(\{0\})$.

The conclusion is that the circle of radius $\varepsilon$ around $(x,y)$ does not contain any points from $g^{-1}(\{0\})$. This means that $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ is not dense.

Comment: I didn't say 'any set'. The g-inverse set of {0} is uncountable, I am asking if this uncountable set contains any dense set. If a,b belongs to this set, where a, b are different, the components of a and b are different. So R×{0} cannot be this set.

Comment: @user398623 I see. So are you basically asking whether the following is true?

\begin{align*}
\phantom{5}
\end{align*}

For any $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist some $x^*,y^*\in\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align*}
|x^*-x|<&\;\varepsilon,\\|y^*-y|<&\;\varepsilon,\quad\qquad\text{and }\\f(x^*)=&\;f(y^*).
\end{align*}

Comment: @user398623 I just amended my answer, for your interest.